# Stuck in while loop even though condition has been met

Tags: ruby

I'm writing this script to build a tic-tac-toe game. This is only the beginning (no turns yet). I want to let the user input again if the previous input is invalid.

```
def display_board(board)
    first_row = " #{board[0]} | #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} "
    second_row = " #{board[3]} | #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} "
    third_row = " #{board[6]} | #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} "
    row_divider = "-----------"
    puts first_row
    puts row_divider
    puts second_row
    puts row_divider
    puts third_row
end  

def valid_move?(board,index)
    if (index >= 0) && (index <= board.length - 1) && (position_taken?(board,index) != FALSE)
        return TRUE
    else
        return FALSE
    end
end

def input_to_index(user_input)
    index = user_input.to_i - 1
    return index
end

def move(board, index, character = "X")
    board[index] = character
end

def position_taken?(board,index)
    if (board[index] == "X") || (board[index]=="O")
      return FALSE
    end
end

def turn(board)
    puts "Please enter 1-9:"
    user_input = gets.strip
    index = input_to_index(user_input)
    while valid_move?(board,index) == FALSE
        puts "invalid"
        turn(board)
    end
    move(board, index, character = "X")
    display_board(board)
end
```

I am stuck on the while loop. If I input an invalid input and then a valid input, it runs through the while loop instead of ending the program. It should be true. The problem is fixed if I use an if statement instead of a while loop, but I want to learn to use while loops better.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `TRUE` and `FALSE` have been spelled `true` and `false` in Ruby for as long as I can remember. My interpreter gives a warning if I use the uppercase versions.

Comment: And take advantage of the mighty boolean: `if x return true else return false` is exactly the same as `return x` (assuming `x` is already a boolean). Similarly, `while x == false` is more commonly written `while not x`.

Comment: Just a suggestion, use short circuit evaluation when possible, they are easy to.

Comment: @Thomas: Or, in Ruby, `until x` (as long as the condition is not too complex).

Comment: @Thomas it might be more commonly written as `while !x` but I wouldn't say it's more commonly written as `while not x`...for me, `not` is most commonly seen in code when I'm fixing the bug someone introduced by using `not` instead of `!`

Comment: @SimpleLime Pardon me, you're right of course, had my head stuck in Python today :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you call "turn" (internal) from "turn" (external) and then the internal "turn" called is valid but the `board` and `index` on the external 
"turn" didn't change.

try this:

```
def turn(board)
    loop do
        puts "Please enter 1-9:"
        user_input = gets.strip
        index = input_to_index(user_input)
        if valid_move?(board,index) == TRUE
            break
        end
        puts "invalid"
    end
    move(board, index, character = "X")
    display_board(board)
end
```

Comment: `break if valid_move?(board, index)` - not need to compare a boolean with true.

Comment: @LarsHaugseth - true, but I kept to the original question format.